# Cloning the events along with an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My question concerns cloning and cloning events.

I have this button:

```xml
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse test">test</button>
```

In my JS:

```js
//create a clone of my button at the start so any later changes to the btn do not effect future clones
var test = $(".test").clone(true);  

$(".test").click(function() {
    alert('a');
});

test.clone(true).insertBefore('#addQuestion');
```

The above clones the button but the event no longer works, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which event no longer works?

Comment: Well, at least in your code sample you are assigning the handler AFTER cloning the `$(".test")` (in line 2).

Comment: Please refer in this 

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are cloning the element before adding listener.

```
var test = $(".test").click(function() {
               alert('a');
           }).clone(true); // .insertBefore('#addQuestion')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7XR9/